# DropDownListFor for part of Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

is there a way to display only part of the enum values in DropDownListFor using EnumHelper.GetSelectList() or just EnumDropDownListFor?

Let's say I got enum like this:

```
public enum Colors
{
    Red= 1,
    Blue= 2,
    Black= 3,
    Green= 4,
    White= 5,
    Yellow= 6
}
```

And I want to display only first 3 colors in the dropdown using Razor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Color, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Colors)), "Select")
```

Comment: Add `.Take(3)` to that collection? Possibly with `.ToList()` as well if that is a requirement. ie. `EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Colors)).Take(3).ToList()`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you :)